# How to solve the issue while using Conv1d?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use auc_roc and accuracy as metrics for binary classification. I am using a simple conv1d with an output dense layer. The code is given below:

'''
df_features = df_features.to_numpy()

```
df_features=df_features.reshape((df_features.shape[0], df_features.shape[1], 1))

df_features.shape
(4076, 62, 1)

auc_roc = tensorflow.keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc_roc',num_thresholds=20000,curve='ROC')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=1, kernel_size=3, strides=1,padding='valid', input_shape=. 
(df_features.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
optimizer=SGD(lr=0.001)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer,metrics=['accuracy',auc_roc])

model.fit(df_features, mind_wandered_label, batch_size = 10, epochs = 50, verbose = 1)
```

'''

Then I get the following error:

```
Epoch 1/50
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-5e51c6c2d167> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(df_features, mind_wandered_label, batch_size = 10, epochs = 50, verbose = 1)
```

packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:1134 assert_is_compatible_with
raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

```
    ValueError: Shapes (None, 60) and (None, 1) are incompatible
```

What could be an issue? If somebody can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you print the size of mind_wandered_label as well?

Comment: mind_wandered_label.shape->(4076,)

Comment: I was not able to replicate your issue. Can you share standalone code to replicate the same? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!